# Why does Angular attempt to route my MVC solution's URL when it sends a get request to Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, asp.net-mvc

I have a very basic MVC solution that just has a button to run an AJAX query to my Angular site. It's a GET request for a component that's on my routes. This Angular site is hosted in IIS and I'm able to access this app and all the routes from the browser.
My goal is to hit this button, get access the Angular app and load the result in a modal, i.e. send a GET request to MyAngularApp/editItemPage/ItemID.

This should return the edit form and its functionality, which I can then stick inside a modal. However, something that keeps happening is that Angular tries to route the Origin URL, i.e. my MVC solution's URL. Obviously this URL isn't in the list of Angular routes, so it returns an error, opens the modal and does nothing:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'MVCAngular'`

The strange thing is however, that after I hit the button a second time, the modal opens and loads the app-root into the modal, which I'm not even requesting. The app-root works in all it's functionality; every part of it is functional, but I don't want to be loading this app-root, I want to load a different component.

Is there something I can do to ensure that the route I specify is what gets loaded, and that Angular doesn't try to route my MVC solution's URL?

EDIT: The AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/AngularApp/edit/1',
    type: 'GET',
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log('error');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(data);
        $('#addModalSolo').modal('toggle');
        $('.modalbody').html(data);
    }
});
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EditLocationSoloComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditLocationSoloComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '/AngularApp/'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [EditLocationSoloComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestAngular</title>
  <base href="/AngularApp/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Angular+MVC is not a good combination. You've got a client-side GUI framework and a server-side GUI framework. There's no need for that really, it's duplication and will start to cause confusion such as you're experiencing now. Better combination would be Angular+Web API - web API is set up to just deliver data, rather than handle GUI interaction.

Comment: Anyway regarding the actual error, we can't specify a definite fix for anything without seeing relevant code. Descriptions of code are, by their very nature, imprecise and potentially ambiguous. Whereas a solution to correct solve your specific problem will need to be precise and definite.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for the repsonse. I've updated the post with some code examples, but honestly I don't know what code I should even be showing. My code isn't anything out of the ordinary, and it seems to be the routing that's messing up, so I figure it could be something in my configuration of routing? I've included code for app.module.ts, index.html and the ajax request itself.